# How do I define OpenGym Observation space with two Text string inputs?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to define a simple OpenGym observation space with two text string inputs. While I am new to this, I've earlier been able to create an observation space with numerical float variables, using the Box type.

I am having a hard time trying to do the same with **text** variables. I tried the following and it gives me an error "`Values of the dict should be instances of gym.Space`" - and I believe this refers to the "`str`" type I am using. However I am not able to figure out how to do this from the documentation ([link](https://github.com/openai/gym/tree/master/gym/spaces)).

```
# Represent an observation. Two text strings
self.observation_space = spaces.Dict({
 "text_1": str,
 "text_2": str
})
```

Appreciate any help or direction you can provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using vectorized text features.